# Proving the equation $C=2x/(1+x^2)^2$ has two positive solutions

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show the equation $C=\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$ has two solutions where $C$ is a constant such that $0<C<\frac{1}{2}$.

My method was to say at $x=1$, $RHS=\frac{1}{2}>C$ and I'm sure you can see my reasoning from there. But is there a smarter way to go about this than just plugging in a number, which may not work for other graphs where there is a tiny interval of the points where the graphs meet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function$$y=\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$ Its derivative write $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-6 x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}$$ and it cancels at $x=\pm \frac 1{\sqrt 3}$. At this point the value of $y$ is $\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{8}$ and the second derivative test would show that this is a maximum. So, for positive $x$, the function increases up to this point and decreases to $0$. So, there are two solutions for any value of $C$ such that $$0\lt C\lt\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{8}$$ Notice that the upper bound I wrote is larger than $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 3):

The [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) gives the result, using

- RHS is continuous
- RHS$(1) > C$
- $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ RHS$(x) = 0 < C$
- RHS$(0) = 0 < C$

This seems like a pretty smart way and it works for arbitrary small intervals.

I'm not sure what is meant by "may not work for other graphs where there is a tiny interval of the points where the graphs meet?", but here is yet another method:

You are looking for positive numbers such that $C(1+x^2)^2 = 2x$. Multiplying out yields $$1-\frac{2}{C}x +2x^2 + x^4 = 0 $$ By [Descartes' rule of sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) this polynomial has either two positive solutions or zero positive solutions.  Now it suffices to find one positive solution.

Another method is to use [Sturm sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for root counting in intervals.

Comment: Surprise, surprise, this is exactly the OP's reasoning. He was asking for an alternative proof.

Comment: I interpret it as the question is about how to make this reasoning rigorous.

Comment: That was my reasoning, but I just didn't write the full details in the question. I mean in this case then $x=1$ was an obvious choice for which we could apply the IVT, but what would we have done if we could not find such a value x, for example if $RHS>C$ only occurred over a tiny interval, say $x\in (97/113,98/113)$, then we could not just guess a value of x and apply IVT.

Comment: Well, you are solving a polynomial equation so before applying IVT you may want to determine max and min, or try similar things to get an idea of how the function behaves.  Anyway, now I mentioned two other methods.